# Having weird redirect issues with site, is this always going to be a server issue?

Tags: wordpress

I can see http://www.webermediapartners.com website when I have the plugins directory not named 'plugins', which changing it to any name will not show up in the WP system since it requires a folder by that name. I [get a messed up login](http://www.ubuntu-pics.de/bild/113834/desk_1_187_bvdnd4.png) and sent to an URL redirect for enternity.

When I rename the plugins dir to 'plugins', the http://www.webermediapartners.com redirects to the famous (by now) http://www.webermediapartners.com/-1 . This is just for the homepage, the rest of the site (internal pages, anything except homepage) shows fine. I [get a messed up login](http://www.ubuntu-pics.de/bild/113834/desk_1_187_bvdnd4.png) and `Not Found` AND an URL redirect for enternity.

So what does this tell us?

If it were a plugin error, you would simply rename the plugin dir to anything but 'plugins' and it would simply deactivate every plugin installed on the site. You would be able to see the site function without plugins fine (content would load, images would load, etc). You would definetely be able to login and function within the Dashboard.

Since we are having weird redirect issues (which is inhibiting us from being able to actually login), as well as redirect issues with the homepage/domain - with the plugins dir named as 'plugins', I am thinking this is more a server setup issue than actual WP issue itself.

Answer (score 0):

> If it were a plugin error, you would simply rename the plugin dir to anything but 'plugins' and it would simply deactivate every plugin installed on the site.

Not quite - if you are experiencing troubles with a particular plugin, *rename the plugin's folder or file*, **not** the entire plugins folder!

Rename your plugins folder back to `plugins`, then delete (or rename) all the plugins *inside* it to deactivate them.